# Quadcopter plummeted into the ocean

Tags: remote-control, lipo, water, underwater

We have a quad copter which had an arm partially detach mid-flight, which in turn destabilized the vehicle, plummeting it into the ocean. After two hours of searching we were finally able to recover the copter which had already suffered severe terminal corrosion. We immediately disconnected the batteries upon pulling it out of the water (a 12v and a 18.5v LiPo,).

My questions:

1. What are your recommendations for de-salenating the electronic components?
2. Are my batteries salvageable? The 18v (Li Po) is puffed up pretty bad, but the 12v (Li Po) appears just fine.
3. Are there any other words of wisdom for this situation?

Currently, the quad copter is sitting in the bath tub filled with water (batteries removed,) as I don't want to expose it to air until we know how to deal with this situation.

Comment: You really don't want to leave it soaking in water, either. Any remaining salts will continue to react with any exposed metal (especially solder joints). You really want to rinse it thoroughly under running water and then dry it as thoroughly as possible. Hot air gun to remove all visible moisture, and then dessicant (or white rice) in a sealed chamber to remove the rest. Then you can start testing to see what still works and what doesn't.

Comment: Do you live near the sea or was this just a rare occasion when you visited our beautiful oceans?

Comment: Coincidentally, I read this story about quadcopters and water a few days ago: http://makezine.com/magazine/drowned-drones-when-a-multicopter-hits-the-water/?utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Make%20Newsletter%20%20Drones&utm_content=Make%20Newsletter%20%20Drones+CID_96896c08d85636544aff0b7a34849f1a&utm_source=Email%20Campaign